# C programming Trie tree heap buffer overflow

Tags: c, memory, tree, trie

I just started programming and have a question:  I want to insert a large amount of words into a trie tree. Then traverse the tree and free all the nodes so that I can insert these words again. But when the number of words is large (say 1 million), I hit a heap buffer overflow, these function works for smaller amount of words:

Here is the nodes

```
struct node
{
    struct node * parent;
    int noempty;
    int isword;
    int super;
    int occurrence;
    int leaf;
    struct node * child[26];
};
```

The function to insert:

```
struct node* insert(struct node *root,char *c)
{
    int i=0;
    struct node *temp=root;
    int l=length(c);
    while(i!=l)
    {
        int index=c[i]-'a';
        if(temp->child[index]==NULL)
        {
            //New Node
            struct node *n=malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
            n->parent=temp;
            temp->child[index]=n;
            temp->noempty=1;
        }
        //Node Exist
        if(i!=l&&temp->leaf==1)
        { 
            temp->leaf=0;
        }
        temp=temp->child[index];
        i++;
    }
    if(temp->noempty==0)
    {
        temp->leaf=1;
    }
    temp->isword=1;
    return root;
};
```

And the free function:

```
void freetree(struct node* curs)
{ 
    int i;
    if(!curs) 
        return;  
    for (i = 0; i !=26; i++)
        freetree(curs->child[i]);
    free(curs);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You `free` 26 nodes but it is not clear that they have memory allocated (or are `NULL` pointers).

Comment: So I need to check if "curs->child[i]==NULL" before "freetree(curs->child[i]);"?

Comment: In the loop `while(i!=l)` neither `i` nor `l` are updated: that's an infinite loop calling `malloc`, whose return value is **not checked**.

Comment: Dear OP, heap size is limited and 1 million words is somewhere in the `10MB` space size which might exceeds the size of the heap.

Comment: @WeatherVane `i++` at the end of the while loop. I've edited this question for a better indentation... waiting for approve.

Comment: @GhostKid Yao no, `free` is OK with a `NULL` pointer, but it is **NOT** ok with an uninitialised pointer.

Comment: @TonyTannous mybad was caught by atrocious formatting.

Comment: @WeatherVane that is fine, now it looks better.

Comment: Still confused about what I should do here, So what should I do to check if I am freeing an initialized pointer?

Comment: To sum up, what is your question OP ? 
Why is it failing for big amount of words ? it is in your title.

Comment: I know it gotta be a error in allocating memory but I'm not sure know how to fix it

Comment: Two ways. 1) match every `free` to its `malloc`. 2) Initialise every pointer to `NULL` before you use any, then `free` is safe, but, if unmatched you can still get a memory leak. So the first is preferable to the scattergun approach.

Comment: is there a way to free the tree with a function instead of matching free to its malloc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the return of the `malloc` function. If it is NULL, it means you have reached the maximum of your heap memory for this process, and thus `malloc` cannot allocate extra memory for you.

Comment: So what should I do instead of malloc?

Comment: If `malloc` cannot allocate extra memory, then it means you cannot allocate memory in a different way.

Comment: For this code it also means you have a serious bug even if you are building a 32 bit application and are only limited to a 2GB address space. You should be no where near any limit. Perhaps you are trying to allocate a negative sized array. Or you are in an infinite loop allocating nodes.

Comment: That's weird because I freed the tree every time and It worked for smaller amount of words.

Comment: My recommendation is to use a debugger to figure out what you are allocating when the allocation fails.